# How to get Count of discrepancy values from two given string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two Strings Paula and Pole. If we check Paula with Pole then we will get three discrepancy a,u,a is present in Paula but not present in Pole so it should return a value 3.

Input:

```
enter string1: Paula 
enter string2: Pole
```

Expected Output:

```
3
```

String 1 is always correct here for a row of names.

I have tried something like below so far

```
import itertools

def compare(string1, string2, no_match_c=' ', match_c='|'):
    if len(string2) < len(string1):
        string1, string2 = string2, string1
    result = ''
    n_diff = 0
    for c1, c2 in itertools.izip(string1, string2):
        if c1 == c2:
            result += match_c
        else:
            result += no_match_c
            n_diff += 1
    delta = len(string2) - len(string1)
    result += delta * no_match_c
    n_diff += delta
    return (result, n_diff)
    
    
def main():
    string1 = 'paula'
    string2 = 'pole'
    result, n_diff = compare(string1, string2, no_match_c='_')

    print(n_diff)
    

main()
```

Answer should be in a function

Example of other string

string1 = Michelle
string2 = Michele

```
Output : 1
```

Comment: why not 5 when `o` and `e` in `string2` are not in `string1`?

Comment: @adamkwm String one is always right so need to check the value which is available in string1 but not not there in string2

Comment: You swap the strings when string2 is longer than string1. How can string1 the always be the correct string?

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? Simple print functions interspersed in your code can help a lot finding out what's going on.

Comment: @9769953 because I will take those data from a row which I have already extracted. Now I have to validate

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach to do what you want, assuming you always want to find the number of chars in string 1 not in string 2.

```
def compare(str1, str2):
    #Return count of chars in str1 not in str2
    s1 = set([x for x in str1])
    s2 = set([x for x in str2])
    ms = s1 ^ s2 & s1  #Finds the chars in string 1 not in str2
    rslt = 0
    for v in ms:
        rslt += str1.count(v)
    return rslt
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `Counter`, it can use to count the number of each character in both strings and support subtraction between counts.

```
from collections import Counter
def diff(s1, s2):
    c1 = Counter(s1)
    c2 = Counter(s2)
    return sum((c1 - c2).values())

print(diff("Paula", "Pole")) # Output: 3
print(diff("Pole", "Paula")) # Output: 2
print(diff("Michelle", "Michele")) # Output: 1
print(diff("Michele", "Michelle")) # Output: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try that, using a list of zeors in the size of 256 (number of ASCII characters) which represents a counter for all characters.

```
def compare(string1, string2):
    chars_counter = [0]*256
    for c1 in string1:
        chars_counter[ord(c1)] += 1
    for c2 in string2:
        if chars_counter[ord(c2)] != 0:
            chars_counter[ord(c2)] -= 1
    return sum(chars_counter)
```